# How to import items from user's JSON File to HTML and set each value as variable

Tags: javascript, json, import, javascript-objects

I am making a website with JS, CSS & HTML (No server side scripts).

I need to import a user's data from a JSON file (Given below is its format):

```
{
  "car": "1320",
  "ship": "1400",
  "plane": "1520",
  "helicopter": "1440",
  "plots": "1,2,3,4",
  "auctionplots": "",
  "carowns": "1",
  "planeowns": "4",
  "helicopterowns": "2",
  "shipowns": "3",
  "addlist": "10,10,20,20,20,30,30,30,40,40,40,50,50,50,60,60,60,70,70,70,80,100",
  "sublist": "10,10,20,22,40,40,40,60,70,70,90,90,90,110,120,120,140,140,140,160,180,200",
  "history": "Server Started,car ~ Bought Plot 1 -60,Plot 1 ~ Rent Updated to 70,helicopter ~ Bought Plot 2 -60,Plot 2 ~ Rent Updated to 70,ship ~ Bought Plot 3 -100,Plot 3 ~ Rent Updated to 120,plane ~ Bought Plot 4 -100,Plot 4 ~ Rent Updated to 120,Plot 4 ~ Rent Updated to 220,car ~ Payed rent ($120) for Plot 4 to plane",
  "session_id": "09042021"
}
```

This is the import page [Monopoly Online](https://rko-monopoly.web.app/import.html)

When I click Import data, each object should be inside a variable, 
For Example :
`"car": "1500"` ,   It's value `(1500)` should be in a variable `car`. 
Is that possible? Or Is there anything else I can do to achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked JSON.parse() method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a solution for you. It parses the whole JSON you put into the text field and put it into the object, so you can do whatever you want to do with it. Please, have a look at the function `parse`

```js
 function show(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible'
 }
 function hide(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden'
}

function parse(idTag) {
  const input = $(idTag).val();
  const object = JSON.parse(input);
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    $('#parsed').append(`<p>${key}: ${value}</p><br>`);
  }
  show('parsed')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css" />
        <link sizes="16x16 24x24 32x32 48x48 64x64" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://monopoly.hasbro.com/images/worldwide_header_hasbro_logo.png" />
        <title>Import Module</title>
        <style>
            textarea#import {
                display:block;
                width: 40pc;
                height: 30pc;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" class="mt-5 centre container-sm contact-form">
                <fieldset>
                    <button onclick="show('results');hide('me');hide('hr');" id="me" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Insert Data&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

                    <hr id="hr"/>
                    <div class="results" id="results" style="visibility: hidden;">
                        <h2>Import Data</h2>
                        <hr />
                        <textarea placeholder="Paste Your JSON File Here" id="import"></textarea>
                        <button onclick="parse('#import')" class="mt-1 btn btn-outline-dark">Import Data&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    
                </fieldset>
        </div>
        
        <div id="parsed">
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I modified the script part a little bit, moved it to an external js file, and removed div#parsed from the import page. Now it is Perfect, Thank You :)

Comment: I am glad it helped you, you can select the best answer and vote for it then. Thank you too :))